# How do I switch the active window and automate GUI changes?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am working on a program that automates some testing at my job using pyautogui. I will have 2 applications that will be open and closed if needed, and one that will run the entire time.

I need to be able to switch which application is my active window, make some gui changes, and then switch active application windows.

I think I'm looking for the right os library function to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give us some code or what you already tried for your solution.

But you could use `pywinauto` package to get and use the application you want by switching them from a `list` and use `pyautogui` if you want to do something. For more details please check the [How does it work](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-does-it-work) documentation.

You can get all applications open from `Desktop` function as:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
window = [w.window_text() for w in windows]
```

So if you `print(window)` you will have for example:

```
['Zoom', 'Dictations - OneNote']
```